# Find all male User with specific Posts SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say i have a Moder `User` that has many `Posts`.

So now for example i choose the Users who are male:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (gender = 'male')
```

How can i extend my search query and select only the male User who have a Post with a tagging `[sport,holiday]`?

If i only had to use `Posts` i would simply call:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."tag" IN ('sport','holiday')
```

So what i tried was:

```
 SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
 WHERE "posts"."tag" IN ('sport', 'holiday') AND gender = 'male'
```

The problem with this search query is that it returns the same User several times if he has more Posts with the tags ['sport','holiday']. How do i have to change my search query so that it returns a User only once? Thanks

Comment: Try grouping by user_id

Comment: `Select Distinct users.* ...`

Comment: That query returns posts that have tags `sport` or `holiday`. Are you sure that's what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY`

`GROUP BY users.id`

or `DISTINCT`

Comment: The former gives extra information if you like:
    `SELECT users.*, count(1) as num_posts FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "posts"."tag" IN ('sport', 'holiday') AND gender = 'male' GROUP BY "users"."id"`

 the latter gives just the users:
   `SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "posts"."tag" IN ('sport', 'holiday') AND gender = 'male'`

Comment: Is this a copy/paste of the comments ? And guesses are for comments not answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
 WHERE "posts"."tag" IN ('sport', 'holiday') AND gender = 'male'
```

Will return unique rows

or as the first comment said use a group by

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
 WHERE "posts"."tag" IN ('sport', 'holiday') AND gender = 'male'
Group by users.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could you use the IN operator with a subquery

```
SELECT "users".* 
FROM "users" 
WHERE "users"."id" IN (
    SELECT "posts"."user_id"
    FROM "posts"
    WHERE "posts"."tag" IN ('sport', 'holiday')
) AND gender = 'male'
```

OR `ANY`

```
SELECT "users".* 
FROM "users" 
WHERE "users"."id" = ANY(
    (
     SELECT ARRAY(
         SELECT "posts"."user_id"
         FROM "posts"
         WHERE "posts"."tag" IN ('sport', 'holiday'))
     )::integer[]
) AND gender = 'male'
```